# What's the difference between character set and font in operating system?

Tags: fonts, operating-system, character

I am wondering that is there some difference between character set and fonts in operating system? . I know character set maps set of characters to their integer value but when fonts comes in to the scene I get vague feeling.. . I wonder how they are related ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Font files contain the information mapping characters (by "index" of the character) to displayable vector or bitmap data. Read http://v1.jontangerine.com/log/2008/08/typeface--font for a better overview.

A character set - see e.g http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xml doesn't involve the keyboard, it is a map from indices (the integer) to a character (conceptual, not a specific glyph).

The thing you describe is named keymap (afaik).

I think that should be enough for your purpose and give you some pointers to delve deeper if you want to.

**UPDATE**
The magical chain (probably a little hazy and I didn't research it, please fix any errors you find):

You press a key on your keyboard - you trigger an interrupt, it's a **key event**. I don't know the wire-protocol between the keyboard and the computer, but I guess it's just a byte per key, something like 0..127 for key down and -1..-128 for key up.

Your operating system receives an interrupt from the keyboard and updates its internal state, aggregating information like ctrl / shift / alt modifiers pressed, ... Knowledge of the layout of your keyboard (**keymap**) and the **charset** you use is taken into account, so you get a character (e.g. key event for "a" + "shift" -> "A", which is easy. But you could also type something like "Ä", which isn't contained in every charset and isn't contained on every keyboard). Now you know which character was pressed. But that's not something you can display - it's just a concept (see next step).

If no hotkey handler or whatnot intercepts your key and it gets through to your application, it needs to know what to draw to the screen or printer. "A"s aren't all alike, if you take two hand-written ones they'll probably look different. **Fonts** are used to draw or print something representing the character - the image of the character. For most users and in most programs, **font** encompasses the look of the characters, the file containing the data to produce it and all variants like **regular**, **bold**, **italic**, **caps** and combinations thereof.

Type experts (I am not one, just an enthusiast) don't really like that lack of distinguation.

A **typeface** is a family of **font** variants (see above) which are stored in **font files** containing descriptive data for the **glyphs** (character with a specific look). The font may also contain **kerning** (distance between characters), **hinting** (specifics on how to display it in certain sizes), **alternatives** (alternate glyphs for a letter) and **ligatures** (how to combine a group of characters into a single glyph. The different font file formats (truetype, open type, all those web-font formats) have different capabilites.

There's bitmap fonts for a single resolution which look mushy if they are not displayed in a multiple of the original bitmap. There's vector fonts containing a mathematical description of their outline which can scale to any resolution you like and may still look crisp (that's where hinting can be important. And cleartype, antialiasing, subpixel antialiasing).

Fonts can be classified by their look: **proportional** ("i" is slimmer than "m") vs **monospace** (every glyph has the same width), **sans serif** vs **serif**. They are classified as **font families** when they have certain similiarities. **grotesque**, **fracture**, **symbol**, **signature**, ...

That's all I've got for now and I probably didn't get everything right. But it's a start. For more details, paste anything bold into your favorite search engine. If you, dear reader, spotted an error: I'd appreciate a comment and will update this.

Comment: I really liked the depth of your answer, Thanks)

Comment: http://v1.jontangerine.com/log/2008/08/typeface--font seems to be down :(

Answer (score 7):

A character set is a mapping from unsigned integers to abstract characters. For example, in the Ascii character set, the number 103 (decimal; 67 in hex) is mapped to the Latin small letter g. At the logical level, a character set need not have anything to do with computers (though the concept has obvious practical relevance in information technology)

A font, in the modern sense of the word, is computer code for rendering (displaying) characters in a particular shape, as specific glyphs.

Internally, a font uses glyph indexes but also index numbers based on a character set. When a font is used to render the letter g, it is internally represented by its number in a character set, and this number is used to find out the glyph(s) for it in the font. That is, the character number is mapped to a glyph number. (If the character set of the text is different from the character set used in the coding of the font, an additional conversion between character sets needs to be performed before this.)

This is often simplified by describing a font as an array of glyphs, indexed by character numbers: the index, say 103, is used to pick up the 103rd virtual box, containing a glyph (for the character g). Although useful to get a basic idea, it’s really an oversimplification. In many fonts, there are two or more glyphs for the letter g (such as a one-loop form and a double-loop form, or a normal form an a small capital form), though one of them is the default glyph and other forms need to be selected with special tools.

Comment: I wished I had enough rep to upvote you! (virtual +1 ?) . Your explanation was great help , Thanks.